# cisco 6500 crash enabling netflow

Tags: networking, cisco, hardware

i have a cisco 6503 running IOS 12.2(33)sxi5 and i'm trying to enable netflow.

Following the instructions here http://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/help/cisco-netflow/cisco-ios-netflow.html enabling for interface vlan 3, shortly after ip flow-export version 5 console outputs:

CPU_MONITOR-6-NOT_HEARD: CPU monitor messages have not been heard for 30 seconds

crashlog here: http://pastebin.com/Niv2H8xD

it then writes a crash log and reloads the router. Has anyone else experienced anything like this before? Here is my running config prior to adding the options in the above link: http://pastebin.com/AgNb1ahG

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Although I totally understand your question it is a little niche and I doubt you'll get a better answer here than you would placing a TAC case. Good luck with it though, I'd appreciate if they help you fix the problem if you'd come back and add some details of how if you would.

Answer (score 1):

You did the right thing gathering the crashinfo, but it may need more analysis to be useful.

Some resources on cisco's website could help you to diagnose this issue (cco account needed):

- See if the [Error message decoder tool](http://www.cisco.com/pcgi-bin/Support/Errordecoder/index.cgi) can explain the logs you're having.
- Check on if there is an entry in the [Cisco bug toolkit](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/BugToolKit/) that could match your issue.

You could also try to search in Cisco NSP (Network Service Providers) [mailing-list archives](https://puck.nether.net/pipermail/cisco-nsp/), and maybe [post](https://puck.nether.net/mailman/listinfo/cisco-nsp) to ask for help.

Last but not least, as Chopper3 suggested it, open [a TAC case](http://tools.cisco.com/ServiceRequestTool/create/) (cco + maintenance contract needed).

Comment: Alternatively, talk to whoever you have a service contract with and have them open a TAC case for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will third opening a TAC case. That is the reson that somany people run Cisco in the network is that when odd things like this happen there is a go to team to find the solution.